# Sending emails to an email with an attachment

Tags: python, django

In the django function, I fill in a docx document template

```
doc = DocxTemplate('template.docx')

dates = date
prices = price

tbl_contents = [{'expirationdate': expirationdate, 'price': price}
                for expirationdate, price in zip(dates, prices)]

context = {
    'tbl_contents': tbl_contents,
    'finalprice': sum(prices),
    'startdate': startdate,
    'enddate': enddate
}

doc.render(context)
doc.save("static.docx")
```

How do I get a file static.docx and send it to email?

I sent ordinary emails via `send_mail` but how do I send emails with an attachment?

Comment: Hope it will help https://studygyaan.com/django/how-to-send-email-with-attachments-in-django

Comment: Can't it be done without SendGrid?

Comment: You can, just use your `EMAIL_HOST`, `EMAIL_PORT` and everything. Удачи! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage


doc = DocxTemplate('template.docx')

dates = date
prices = price

tbl_contents = [{'expirationdate': expirationdate, 'price': price}
                for expirationdate, price in zip(dates, prices)]

context = {
    'tbl_contents': tbl_contents,
    'finalprice': sum(prices),
    'startdate': startdate,
    'enddate': enddate
}

doc.render(context)
file_io = BytesIO()
doc.save(file_io)


email = EmailMessage(subject="subject", body="mail Body", from_email="from@example.com", to=["to1@example.com", "to2@example.com"])
email.attach("static.docx", file_io.getvalue(), 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
email.send()
```

Comment: Error     raise TypeError(msg) from err
TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not DocxTemplate